# how to access a particular attribute of plotBands in highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

```
    var pB=[];  //later I have assigned **plotBands: pB,**
    pB[i]={
        from:tA[i],
        to: tA[i+1],
        label: { 
        text: wA[i], // Content of the label. 
        align: 'center'},
        color: '#eef',
        events: {
            click: function(){

                console.log("from: "+this.from);

                console.log("duration: "+this.(to-from));
            }
       }
    }
```

I want to access the **from** value in the above example for each pB[i]. How do I do that ? **from** has a numeric value.`enter code here` *console.log("from: "+this.from);* outputs "undefined".

Comment: May be I'm wrong, but you can't call it **from**: [Javascript From](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: @Vixed `from` here is not an javascript method, but a highcharts object's field. @Rajni where do you want to access it from?

Comment: @Rahul
I want to access in :

        events:{
            click : function() {

               // here, i.e. whenever any plotband is clicked
    }}

Comment: you should be able to get from parameter by using this.options.from. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/7eba7h2r/

Comment: Thank you @Grzegorz for the help . It worked.